# Export PPT slide to JPG

Tags: excel, vba, export, powerpoint, jpeg

I'm trying to save a slide from PPT through VBA, but there is something wrong with the code, because it runs but it doesn't give me anything...  no file is created

```
Sub saveimage()

Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pppres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim xSlide As Slide
On Error GoTo Err_ImageSave

Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

With pppres.Slides(1)
.Export "C:\Users\msr\Documents\Projetos" & "Slide1" & ".jpg", "JPG"

End With

Err_ImageSave:
If Err <> 0 Then
MsgBox Err.Description
End If

End Sub
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks,
M

Comment: Did you by chance mean `"C:\Users\msr\Documents\Projetos\" & "Slide1" & ".jpg", "JPG"`? Note the backslash after `Projetos`.

Comment: That's it, it worked!!